# Crystal Reports no muestra campos nuevos

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

¿Alguien que me pudiera decir ¿Por qué no se ven los campos que pongo en `crystal report`?
He intentado todo lo que he encontrado, pero nada funciona.
Como se ve en la siguiente imagen agrego los campos de **info2** y el de @**codigo barra**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo ejecuto no los muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la parte de info2 esta contenida tambien en @codigo barra

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu seccion `Detalles` tienes el campo `info2` y muestra los datos bien,  entonces antes que nada, verifica que los campos `info2` y `@codigo barra` del pie de informe y pie de pagina no estén configurados con alguna formula para `suprimir` con alguna condición (los campos, NO la sección porque se nota que no esta suprimida)

Comment: no lo estan ya los cheque, pero no, todo esta bien

Comment: Prueba imprimir un `Count` de esos dos campos en el pie del informe a ver si te muestra la cantidad que contiene

Comment: no, no la muestra, ya intente poner un campo de varias formas y no la muestra

Comment: Mmm, en el diseñador de Crystal Report da click derecho encima del uno de los dos campos y pulsa la opcion `Buscar Datos de Campo (Browse Field Data)` Si ahí no muestra nada, quiere decir que esos campos están en blanco y por eso no muestra nada.

Comment: pero es raro, si los muestra, pero si copio un campo que si se muestra normalmente y lo pego por decir en el pie de pagina no se muestra, la opcion que me da das ya le hecho, solo me muestra el tipo de campo que es y la longitud que tiene

Comment: Me temo que no se que mas sugerirte dado que no puedo ver el escenario en sí, para poder sugerirte algo mas.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema lo raro es que en vista previa del reporte si se ven el campo pero cuando mando llamar el reporte del programa ahí ya no se ve.

Comment: ok creo que ya lo resilvo.. en mi caso no se vizualiza el campo porque en mi consulta sql lo ando llamando con un alias diferente al su nombre original dela tabla. es decir como alias le tuve que poner el mismo nombre del campo y asi ya me lo reconoce.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es seleccionar todos tus campos en el select con un *, yo estaba especificando cada campo en la consulta, ahora en el reporte ahi obviamente si especifica solo los campos que deseas ver

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer]. Además yo diría que la respuesta no es lo suficientemente apropiada, porque la columna info2 si viene en la query, porque se muestra, en el reporte.